# CSS Positioning of Text Block for all Screen Sizes

Tags: css, position, css-position

For a website I have background picture that has full width on each page.
Some of the pages have a "description box" on the bottom left corner of this background picture.

The problem is, I struggle to keep it at the same position for varying screen sizes.

I gave the background area the class "banner1" and made it relative, so that the description text box section in it can have an absolute position.

The text box has the class "huaxin1".

The original position in Elementor for the text box section was directly in the middle of the background section, so I had to put bottom: -1000%;
left: -50%; to position it on the bottom left. It failed to stay in that position as the screen size varied.

Any ideas on how to fix this for all devices and screen sizes?

```css
.banner1 {
  position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  .huaxin1 {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 1rem 2rem 1rem 1rem;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    right: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) {
  .huaxin1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 1rem;
    bottom: -1000%;
    left: -50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- YOUR HTML HERE -->
```

Comment: I am unsure what HTML exactly you want and how to get it... I explained it in some detail already. Each page of the website has a header on top, then the background image. Some of the background images have a description box, this box needs to stay at the same position regardless of changing screen sizes.

Comment: There are countless questions presented exactly like this. I have read the page, yet I still do not know how to get the HTML that you desired and you don't want to tell me. I found the solution myself anyway: margin: auto and "top: 10; left: 10; bottom: 0; right: 10;" was the important part. No amount of HTML would have bettered the problem. I can list off all my computer's specs and my birth certificate, but that will not help the problem. So thanks for nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:

```css
.banner1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
    
.huaxin1 { 
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10; left: 10; bottom: 0; right: 10;
  bottom: -200px;
  left: 1%;
}
```

I hid the text section for mobile and tablet, though, because on those devices it gets pushed too far down and out of the background picture. This is good enough for now, though.

If someone knows how to fix this last part, feel free to share.